# Sharepoint 2010 sends error 404 once per user after deployment or application pool restart

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, error-handling

We have a big SharePoint-Project we installed on different servers. Whenever we deploy any feature/webpart the first access of ANY page (including Backend Pages like "ManageFeatures.aspx") throws a 404 Error.

This happens once for *every* user

I included a httphandler (IHttpModule) to catch those errors to get more information. In that handler I found out that while this error is thrown SPContext.Current is null.

When I call that page a second time the 404 is gone and the page is shown correctly. This is not a sporadic error but happens every time we deploy something.

Any clue what causes this behavior and how to avoid this?

(We got the error on all of our 10 machines)

Answer (score 0):

Try to represent this error with default master-page.